# Set startdate to countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have a countdown that ends at a specific time and date.
Is it possible to set a starting date for the countdown?

**Start**: June 14, 2018 15:00:00
**End**: June 17, 2018 23:59:59

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("June 17, 2018 23:59:59").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "TEXT Countdown" + days + " days, " + hours + " h, "
    + minutes + " min & " + seconds + " sec";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "TEXT after countdown";
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: `var countDownDate = new Date("June 17, 2018 23:59:59").getTime();` That string isn't in [the only format `new Date` is required to parse](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format). Strongly recommend using the correct format. Even if the browser's JavaScript engine in the browser you happen to use to test works, that doesn't mean others will (or in other locales).

Answer (score 0):

Just delay the call to `setInterval` until the time you want. Your best bet, since timers get throttled on inactive tabs, is to check periodically and then kick things off when the time arrives:

```
var waitingTimer = setInterval(function() {
    if (Date.now() < Date.parse("2018-06-14T15:00:00")) {
        return;
    }
    clearInterval(waitingTimer);
    // ...start the countdown
}, 1000);
```

You might want to express the time in UTC, since unfortunately the spec on what those strings mean without a timezone indicator changed (twice), whereas if you put the time in UTC and add a `Z` to the string, it's reliable.

Comment: I dont get it to work, how would you write the code?